# Filtered data from React Table

Tags: react-table

I am using the react-table. And I need to get the data after the filter  for the purpose of excel export. But still, there is no way to catch those. Any idea

Comment: please provide a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your existing code

Answer (score 0):

I think, according to [react-table documentation](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/examples/basic), you can access the filtered data, when it is rendering (through the variable **rows**); the example code can be like so:

```html
  <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map((row, i) => {
            prepareRow(row)
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map(cell => {
                  return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                })}
              </tr>
            )
          })}
  </tbody>
```